# How to export result from callback javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

How to export result from callback javascript to global variable

```
function capsule (a, b, callback) {
    var res = a + b
    callback( res )
}


capsule(5, 2, n => {
    var result = n
    // console.log(result)
})

// i need do operation with result here, outside the callback
console.log(result) // result is undefined
console.log("ok")
```

The console back result is undefined

Comment: If `capsule` is synchronous, it should not take a callback but just `return` the result. If it asynchronous, you cannot export the future value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> capsule(5, 2, n => {
>     var result = n
> ```

`var` declares a variable that is *local* to the function.

Declare it *outside*

```
var result;

capsule(5, 2, n => {
    result = n
```

---

It would probably make more sense to *return* the value rather than to use a callback though:

```
function capsule (a, b) {
    var res = a + b;
    return res;
}

var result = capsule(5, 2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I thinked 'var' make global variables and 'let' local

Comment: @DenisRohlinsky — No. `var` makes them local to the function. `let` makes them local to the block.

Answer (score 0):

`result` is only defined inside of your callback. If you define it outside, it will work.

```
function capsule (a, b, callback) {
    var res = a + b
    callback( res )
}

var result;
capsule(5, 2, n => {
    result = n
})

console.log(result)
console.log("ok")
```